# GeoGraph based on (x,y)-coordinates

Tags: geography, geographics

To create a Geograph we use a longitude and latitude to visualize the exact positions. I work with a database without the lon/lat. Instead of that, my database has a X and Y coordinate. I know, there is a complex formula to translate this (X,Y)-coordinates tot a Lon/Lat.

My question is: can Mathematica deal with (X,Y)-coordinates to create a GeoGraph.
For example:
x-coördinaat:118609
y-coördinaat:485297

This is a position in Amsterdam, Netherlands

Comment: Take a look at [GeoGridPosition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGridPosition.html).

Comment: Do you know what EPSG coordinate system your coordinates are in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information about conversion between different geographical co-ordinate systems in the Mathematica Documentation, for example under `ref/GeoPositionXYZ`. Not knowing what standard your X-Y system is based on makes it hard to say much more.